# What are definitions of Display Formula and Numbered Formula?

Tags: lyx, terminology

Can you help me, please!

What are definitions of Display Formula and Numbered Formula ?

Answer (score 4):

in mathematical publishing, a display (somewhat more general than
"display formula") is material that is set off from the text block,
typically centered, and typically with some extra vertical space above
and below it.  the usual purpose is to highlight the material, although
in the case of a math expression, it may be necessary to set it outside
the text block because the expression cannot be broken in a reasonable
manner or it otherwise unduly disrupts the appearance of the text block;
material placed as a display for that reason is usually not numbered.

a "numbered formula" is a subset of the display structural element which
carries a (usually) unique number, usually set at a margin.  the number
is sometimes set on the right and sometimes on the left.

mathematical texts often contain theorems and proofs.  the latter are
conventionally terminated by a distinct symbol (the "qed" marker),
which is most often flush against the right-hand margin.  in that situation, if a proof ends with a numbered display, the number would
conflict with the qed marker, so some math publishers have a "house style" in which equation numbers are placed at the left margin.

i've added [terminology] to your tag designation because, although these
terms may be used to name specific elements for lyx, their use is more
widespread, and indeed traditional in math publishing.